# How to prevent screen rotation in j2me?

Tags: java-me, rotation

I'm programming in j2me.
How can I prevent screen rotation in j2me for all phones that support screen rotation?

thanks.

Comment: show the code for the screen where you would want to prevent rotation

Comment: this is indeed a bigger problem than it looks. you need to tell us whether you are using Form, Canvas or LWUIT and confirm that you really mean it when you say "all phones" because that could actually mean that there is no solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to manifest

For Nokia devices:
*Nokia-MIDlet-App-Orientation : Landscape*

For Samsung devices:
*MIDlet-ScreenMode : Landscape*

Answer (score 2):

If you use Canvas to draw your screen (not LCDUI, not LWUIT, not any other framework) you may implement sizeChanged method to be notified when the rotation happens.

In such case you may draw your screen to an Image and use Sprite to rotate it. For example, to support only Landscape mode I used below code at constructor:

```
    int width = Math.max(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
    int height = Math.min(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
    // screen and sprite are attributes
    screen = Image.createImage(width, height);
    sprite = new Sprite(screen);
    if (super.getWidth() < super.getHeight()) { // portrait screen
        sprite.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT90);
        sprite.setPosition(0, 0);
    }
```

And following methods:

```
    public void sizeChanged (int w, int h) {
        // lastWidth and lastHeight are attributes
        lastWidth = w;
        lastHeight = h;
        if (sprite == null)  return;
        if (super.getWidth() < super.getHeight()) { // portrait screen
            sprite.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT90);
        } else {
            sprite.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_NONE);
        }
        sprite.setPosition(0, 0);
    }

    protected void paint(Graphics g1) {
        if (super.getWidth() != lastWidth
            || super.getHeight() != lastHeight) {
            sizeChanged(super.getWidth(), super.getHeight());
        }
        Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();
        // ... do your drawing on g
        this.sprite.setImage(screen, screen.getWidth(), screen.getHeight());
        sprite.paint(g1);
    }
```

As seen at http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2009/08/fullscreen-landscape.html and http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2010/03/adapting-to-sizechanged.html and http://smallandadaptive.blogspot.com.br/2011/04/sizechanged-not-called.html